# help understanding how to graph a product function

Tags: graphing-functions

to everyone. Please someone help me about graphs of product functions. How to start and how can I graph these type of functions?

e.g. (e^x)sinx

Answer (score 0):

There are no special tricks for "product functions".

Here's a hint for this particular problem: $\sin$ oscillates back and forth between $\pm 1$, and you know where the maxima and minima a roots are. Then 
$$
e^x \sin(x)
$$
oscillates back and forth between $\pm e^x$.

So start with the graph of the exponential function and sketch in the oscillations.